# Hide results when field is blank in a search/filter list group

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list group where all results are initially hidden and only visible when found using search field by name. I need the results to back to hidden state when the search field is blank (example backspaced or deleted and not input present).

https://jsfiddle.net/Nick_Chand/tpyca68k/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myList li").hide();
});
</script>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Header Text</h3>
<h4>Header Subtext</h4>
  <p>Paragraph subtext</p>  
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <li class="list-group-item">Acme Industries <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Marvel Entertainment <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">007 Enterprises <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">DC Comics <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
  </ul>  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: please choose one of many answers as solved. because your question remains open.

Answer (score 1):

You can include a test in your `keyup` event handler that the value is empty, and if so, hide all the elements. Otherwise, search the elements for matches and show them. Note that your code also searches the "Go to ordering portal" text; you may want to include the text you actually want to search into (for example) a span (as I have done in the snippet) to prevent that happening. Note also that for what you are doing `$.each` is more appropriate than $.filter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").hide();
    if (value !== '') {
      var spans = $("#myList li span.search").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
      });
      $(spans).each(function() {
        $(this).parent().show();
      });
      $('#contact').toggle(spans.length);
    }
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myList li").hide();
  $('#contact').hide();
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Header Text</h3>
    <h4>Header Subtext</h4>
    <p>Paragraph subtext</p>
    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
    <br>
    <div id="contact">No results found - fill in form below to contact us</div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="search">Acme Industries</span> <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="search">Marvel Entertainment</span> <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="search">007 Enterprises</span> <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"><span class="search">DC Comics</span> <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Excellent. That works. Anyway to add something like “no results found - Click here to fill form to contact us”

Comment: @NickChand note I've edited the answer so you can avoid searching the `Go to ordering portal` text, which otherwise matches all entries when you enter `er` in the search box.

Comment: I guess. Sorry I am not too familiar. Right now, I have a separate HTML element under above search field and when user isn’t able to find a company name, I am expecting them to respond in the separate form I have below above.

Comment: @NickChand please see my edit. I've added a div into which can show that message. You could potentially add a button to click in that div to go to the form

Comment: Thank you this works but slight problem. The bootstrap stylesheet used is modifying the layout of my wordpress page. It's overwriting the theme font and layouts.

Comment: @NickChand that sounds like a new question to me...

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in a condition `if`.

And **don't duplicate** event `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myList li").hide();

  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (value !== '' ) {
    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });   
    } else {
      $("#myList li").hide();   
    }    
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Header Text</h3>
<h4>Header Subtext</h4>
  <p>Paragraph subtext</p>  
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <li class="list-group-item">Acme Industries <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Marvel Entertainment <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">007 Enterprises <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">DC Comics <a class="btn btn-success" href=# role="button">Go to ordering portal</a></li>
  </ul>  
</div>
</body>
```